# location "/app" cannot be inside the named location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to configure a nginx reverse-proxy server to redirect requests to different servers depending on :

- the endpoint
- whether it is a plain web request or a websocket upgrade request

I know I can use locations to manage the first point, and named locations to manage the second point, but how can I do both?

```
server {
    listen              80 default_server;
    listen              [::]:80 default_server;

    location /app {
        location @web {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:9080/app;
        }

        location @ws {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9081;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection "Upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error message `location "/app" cannot be inside the named location "@web"`

What am I supposed to do to managed that kind of mixed trafic

Comment: What are you basing your assumptions on? I have never seen named locations used like that.

Comment: @RichardSmith I base my assumptions on a config I am using for another server, which you can see on https://gist.github.com/sinderw/1ff7abefa28da4b9dfea37cee823a354
This config separates websocket upgrade request and regular http requests, and do work

Comment: You're missing the `map` and the `@$type` parts.

Comment: Oh right thanks it works now, it seems that I don't understand what the `@$type` means then

Comment: It's a variable based on the `map` and resolves to `@web` or `@ws` to select the correct named location. I didn't know you could use a variable in an `@` expression, but it obviously works. I've learned something today.

Comment: Oh right, so it means I could have used `try_files /nonexistent @$http_upgrade;` then `location @websocket {` without the `map` ?

Comment: Map is cleaner as it handles missing and unknown values correctly.